# fade out of alphabet onkeypress of letter equal to value in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a riddle to my website and i've got the question template. below

```
<table width="474" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">
    <tr>
      <td width="41"><label for="riddle">Riddle</label></td>
      <td colspan="6">What goes up and never comes down?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="52"><div id="div1" class="answerbox">A</div></td>
      <td width="25"><div id="div2"class="answerbox">S</div></td>
      <td width="50"><div id="div3"class="answerbox">D</div></td>
      <td width="50"><div id="div4"class="answerbox">F</div></td>
      <td width="50"><div id="div5"class="answerbox">G</div></td>
      <td width="52"><div id="div6"class="answerbox">H</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div id="div7"class="answerbox">K</div></td>
      <td><div id="div8"class="answerbox">L</div></td>
      <td><div id="div9"class="answerbox">M</div></td>
      <td><div id="div10"class="answerbox">N</div></td>
      <td><div id="div11"class="answerbox">O</div></td>
      <td><div id="div12"class="answerbox">P</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anwer</td>
      <td colspan="6"><label for="answer"></label>
      <input name="answer" type="text" id="answer" size="40" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7"><div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

what i want to achieve its when the user starts to type the answer in the answer textbox, any letter he or she types that is in the div's with the class of `"answerbox"` should fade out if he or she presses backspace to erase the answer the letter fade in back in the div

here's a fiddle to the question

http://jsfiddle.net/q4xhwwrb/

Comment: i don't have a javascript

Comment: This could be start: http://jsfiddle.net/q4xhwwrb/1/ You will need additional conditions (to check if only letter is typed), but, you got idea....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle a bit (after fork) and added reference to jQuery 1.11

http://jsfiddle.net/71n57pot/3/

the biggest part to note is the "keyup" event:

```
$("#answer").on("keyup",function(e){ ... });
```

It doesn't function with the keydown or keypress functions because the value of the "answer" input doesn't change before then

It might start you down your path - You might want to add a bit of tweaking to account for letters pressed that aren't in your selected letters of choice.  I have added support for multiple instances of the same letter as well.

Happy Coding!